# Translation of a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable set. Is it true that if $\ \forall r\in(0,1)$
$$A\cap (A+r)\neq \emptyset$$
then $\lambda(A)>0$?
$$$$
I think that is linked to the Vitali set, but I did't manage to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take for instance the Cantor set on $[0,1]$

We have that $m(C)=0$ and  $C-C=[-1,1]$

Thus $(0,1) \subseteq C-C\Longrightarrow C \cap(C+r) \neq \emptyset,\forall r \in (0,1)$

Comment: Could ou please explain (or give a link) why $C-C=[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: @OlivierRoche here you can find some proofs... https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/cantor3.shtml

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @OlivierRoche you are welcome..also here in MSE you can find a proof that $C+C=[0,2]$..but i believe it has the same idea as in the proof  of $C-C=[-1,1]$